# AWS Glue job succeeds with DynamoDB and MySQL but the data isn't there

Tags: aws-glue

I've got data in DynamoDB and want to extract it and put it in a MySQL database (AWS RDS). I've got AWS Glue setup with a crawler for the DynamoDB table and a crawler for the MySQL database table. These both succeed and create tables in the DataCatalog.

When I then run an ETL job that takes the DynamoDB table in the datacatalog and then maps it and puts into the MySQL database, it appears to succeed (logs below) but then when I look at the MySQL database there's nothing there.

There are c.20 rows in the table I'm using as a test, and so the log would appear to have been able to collect the DynamoDB data, and have attempted to insert it into the MySQL database - but without success.

Fearing that maybe there was a rogue value in the data, I've dropped all but the most vanilla of columns ('title' containing a short string) and it still generates the same result.

If anyone can offer advice or any insight from the log below, I'd be grateful. I've removed IP addresses and anything resembling a hash/identifier.

The only other observation is that when I check the error logs of the MySQL instance, I see line after line of this, which seems to imply an out of memory issue: "(oscar_oom.cc:1210)". So I restarted the instance and upgraded it to a larger size just to check. It also made no difference.

```
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO LogPusher: stopping
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO ProcessLauncher: postprocessing
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: save at JDBCUtils.scala:978, took 23.890680 s
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 1: Stage finished
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 is finished. Cancelling potential speculative or zombie tasks for this job
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 11.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 12) in 5626 ms on x.x.x.48 (executor 3) (20/20)
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (save at JDBCUtils.scala:978) finished in 5.692 s
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 15.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 16) in 5621 ms on x.x.x.48 (executor 3) (19/20)
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) in 5624 ms on x.x.x.48 (executor 3) (18/20)
23/08/07 16:29:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) in 5624 ms on x.x.x.48 (executor 3) (17/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 9.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10) in 5248 ms on x.x.x.78 (executor 4) (16/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 13.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 14) in 5244 ms on x.x.x.78 (executor 4) (15/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6) in 5245 ms on x.x.x.78 (executor 4) (14/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) in 5245 ms on x.x.x.78 (executor 4) (13/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 12.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 13) in 5056 ms on x.x.x.75 (executor 2) (12/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5) in 5053 ms on x.x.x.75 (executor 2) (11/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 5055 ms on x.x.x.75 (executor 2) (9/20)
23/08/07 16:29:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 8.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9) in 5049 ms on x.x.x.75 (executor 2) (10/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 18.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 19) in 185 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (8/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 19.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 20) in 147 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (7/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 17.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 18) in 185 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (6/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 16.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 17) in 180 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (5/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 10.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11) in 3130 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (4/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 19.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 20) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 19, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 14.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 15) in 3097 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (3/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7) in 3100 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (2/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 3101 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (1/20)
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 18.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 19) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 18, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 17.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 18) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 17, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:29:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 16.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 17) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 16, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:29:01 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to x.x.x.48:33922
23/08/07 16:29:01 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to x.x.x.78:35480
23/08/07 16:29:01 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to x.x.x.75:48354
23/08/07 16:29:00 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to x.x.x.100:52348
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.48:46011 (size: 25.9 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.75:38021 (size: 25.9 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.78:46395 (size: 25.9 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.100:41023 (size: 25.9 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 15.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 16) (x.x.x.48, executor 3, partition 15, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 13.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 14) (x.x.x.78, executor 4, partition 13, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 14.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 15) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 14, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 11.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 12) (x.x.x.48, executor 3, partition 11, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 12.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 13) (x.x.x.75, executor 2, partition 12, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 9.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10) (x.x.x.78, executor 4, partition 9, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 10.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 10, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) (x.x.x.48, executor 3, partition 7, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9) (x.x.x.75, executor 2, partition 8, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 6, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5) (x.x.x.75, executor 2, partition 4, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6) (x.x.x.78, executor 4, partition 5, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) (x.x.x.48, executor 3, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (x.x.x.75, executor 2, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) (x.x.x.78, executor 4, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 20 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at save at JDBCUtils.scala:978) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 20 tasks resource profile 0
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1570
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.65:39309 (size: 25.9 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 25.9 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 56.5 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at save at JDBCUtils.scala:978), which has no missing parents
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 1)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set()
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (rdd at DynamicFrame.scala:1948) finished in 18.056 s
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 2650 ms on x.x.x.100 (executor 1) (1/1)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO MultipartUploadOutputStream: close closed:false s3://aws-glue-assets-hash-eu-west-2/sparkHistoryLogs/spark-application-hash.inprogress
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager x.x.x.75:38021 with 5.8 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, x.x.x.75, 38021, None)
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: connected executor 2
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO JESSchedulerBackend$JESAsSchedulerBackendEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (x.x.x.75:48354) with ID 2,  ResourceProfileId 0
23/08/07 16:28:59 INFO ExecutorEventListener: Got executor added event for 2 @ 1691425739067
23/08/07 16:28:58 INFO LogPusher: uploading /tmp/spark-event-logs/ to s3://aws-glue-assets-hash-eu-west-2/sparkHistoryLogs/
23/08/07 16:28:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.100:41023 (size: 9.3 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager x.x.x.48:46011 with 5.8 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(3, x.x.x.48, 46011, None)
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: connected executor 3
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO ExecutorEventListener: Got executor added event for 3 @ 1691425736989
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO JESSchedulerBackend$JESAsSchedulerBackendEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (x.x.x.48:33922) with ID 3,  ResourceProfileId 0
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (x.x.x.100, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4300 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager x.x.x.78:46395 with 5.8 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(4, x.x.x.78, 46395, None)
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager x.x.x.100:41023 with 5.8 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, x.x.x.100, 41023, None)
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO ExecutorEventListener: Got executor added event for 4 @ 1691425736625
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: connected executor 4
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO JESSchedulerBackend$JESAsSchedulerBackendEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (x.x.x.78:35480) with ID 4,  ResourceProfileId 0
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: connected executor 1
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO ExecutorEventListener: Got executor added event for 1 @ 1691425736605
23/08/07 16:28:56 INFO JESSchedulerBackend$JESAsSchedulerBackendEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (x.x.x.100:52348) with ID 1,  ResourceProfileId 0
23/08/07 16:28:56 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[7] at rdd at DynamicFrame.scala:1948) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1570
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.65:39309 (size: 9.3 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 9.3 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 19.6 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[7] at rdd at DynamicFrame.scala:1948), which has no missing parents
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (save at JDBCUtils.scala:978) with 20 output partitions
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (save at JDBCUtils.scala:978)
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 7 (rdd at DynamicFrame.scala:1948) as input to shuffle 0
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: save at JDBCUtils.scala:978
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 28.144541 ms
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO GlueJDBCSink: Use batch insert with batchSize of 1000
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO GlueCloudWatchReporter: About to enter executor
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO JDBCWrapper$: INFO: using ssl properties: Map(trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl -> file:/opt/amazon/certs/RDSTrustStore.jks, useSSL -> true, trustCertificateKeyStorePassword -> , verifyServerCertificate -> true)
23/08/07 16:28:41 INFO JDBCWrapper$: enforceSSL = true, from connection properties, will only attempt SSL with CN matching
23/08/07 16:28:40 INFO GlueContext: The DataSink in action for the given format/connectionType (mysql) is com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.MySqlDataSink
23/08/07 16:28:40 INFO GlueContext: Glue secret manager integration: secretId is not provided.
23/08/07 16:28:40 INFO DataCatalogWrapper: Encrypted Catalog password  empty, using value of unencrypted Catalog password
23/08/07 16:28:40 INFO GlueContext: Using location: databasename.tablename
23/08/07 16:28:40 INFO GlueContext: getCatalogSink: catalogId: null, nameSpace: databasename, tableName: aur_databasename_tablename, isRegisteredWithLF: false
23/08/07 16:28:40 INFO LakeformationRetryWrapper$: Lakeformation: API call succeeded
23/08/07 16:28:40 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 183.305423 ms
23/08/07 16:28:35 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/tmp/spark-warehouse'.
23/08/07 16:28:35 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
23/08/07 16:28:35 INFO GlueCloudWatchReporter: About to enter executor
23/08/07 16:28:35 INFO JDBCWrapper$: INFO: using ssl properties: Map(trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl -> file:/opt/amazon/certs/RDSTrustStore.jks, useSSL -> true, trustCertificateKeyStorePassword -> , verifyServerCertificate -> true)
23/08/07 16:28:35 INFO JDBCWrapper$: enforceSSL = true, from connection properties, will only attempt SSL with CN matching
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO JDBCJobBookmarkUtil$: Skip JDBC Bookmark, Bookmark is not enabled or transformationContext is empty.
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO GlueContext: The DataSource in action : com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO GlueContext: Glue secret manager integration: secretId is not provided.
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO GlueContext: nameSpace: databasename, tableName: aur_databasename_tablename, connectionName aurora-databasestaging, vendor: mysql
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO DataCatalogWrapper: Encrypted Catalog password  empty, using value of unencrypted Catalog password
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO GlueContext: getCatalogSource: transactionId: <not-specified> asOfTime: <not-specified> catalogPartitionIndexPredicate: <not-specified> 
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO GlueContext: getCatalogSource: catalogId: null, nameSpace: databasename, tableName: aur_databasename_tablename, isRegisteredWithLF: false, isGoverned: false, isRowFilterEnabled: false, useAdvancedFiltering: false
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO LakeformationRetryWrapper$: Lakeformation: API call succeeded
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: x.x.x.0 Proxy Port: 8888
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on x.x.x.65:39309 in memory (size: 33.7 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:34 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on x.x.x.65:39309 in memory (size: 33.7 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO AWSConnectionUtils$: AWSConnectionUtils: use proxy in glue client configuration. Host: x.x.x.0, Port: 8888
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: x.x.x.0 Proxy Port: 8888
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO AWSGlueJobBookmarkService: AWSGlueJobBookmarkService: create JES client with proxy: host x.x.x.0, port 8888
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DynamoConnection.scala:53
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.65:39309 (size: 33.7 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 33.7 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 361.7 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DynamoConnection.scala:53
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.65:39309 (size: 33.7 KiB, free: 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 33.7 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 361.7 KiB, free 5.8 GiB)
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO AvroReaderUtil$: Creating default Avro field parser for version 1.7.
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO FileListPersistence: create FileListPersistence with conf: fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId: None
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev hash]
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
23/08/07 16:28:33 INFO GlueContext: GlueMetrics configured and enabled
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: executor task g-hash created for executor 4
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO TaskGroupInterface: createChildTask API response code 200
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO TaskGroupInterface: creating executor task for executor 4; clientToken gr_hash_e_4_a_spark-application-hash
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: executor task g-hash created for executor 3
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO JESSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO log: Logging initialized @9834ms to org.sparkproject.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: executor task g-hash created for executor 2
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO TaskGroupInterface: creating executor task for executor 3; clientToken gr_hash_e_3_a_spark-application-hash
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO TaskGroupInterface: creating executor task for executor 2; clientToken gr_hash_e_2_a_spark-application-hash
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO ExecutorTaskManagement: executor task g-hash created for executor 1
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO SingleEventLogFileWriter: Logging events to file:/tmp/spark-event-logs/spark-application-hash.inprogress
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO GlueCloudwatchSink: CloudwatchSink: jobName: databasename_dyn2aur jobRunId: jr_hash
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: x.x.x.0 Proxy Port: 8888
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO GlueCloudwatchSink: CloudwatchSink: Obtained credentials from the Instance Profile
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO GlueCloudwatchSink: GlueCloudwatchSink: get cloudwatch client using proxy: host x.x.x.0, port 8888
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, x.x.x.65, 39309, None)
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, x.x.x.65, 39309, None)
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager x.x.x.65:39309 with 5.8 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, x.x.x.65, 39309, None)
23/08/07 16:28:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, x.x.x.65, 39309, None)
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on x.x.x.65:39309
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 39309.
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO TaskGroupInterface: creating executor task for executor 1; clientToken gr_hash_e_1_a_spark-application-hash
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: x.x.x.0 Proxy Port: 8888
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO JESSchedulerBackend: JESClusterManager: Initializing JES client with proxy: host: x.x.x.0, port: 8888
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO JESSchedulerBackend: JESSchedulerBackend
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO JESSchedulerBackend$JESAsSchedulerBackendEndpoint: JESAsSchedulerBackendEndpoint
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO SubResultCacheManager: Sub-result caches are disabled.
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 5.8 GiB
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-hash
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
23/08/07 16:28:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 45977.
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication enabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark); groups with modify permissions: Set()
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpus at 4 tasks per executor
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 4, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 10240, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: nativespark-databasename_dyn2aur-jr_hash
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/08/07 16:28:30 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.0-amzn-1
23/08/07 16:28:28 INFO SafeLogging: Initializing logging subsystem
23/08/07 16:28:26 INFO PlatformInfo: Unable to read clusterId from /var/lib/info/job-flow.json, out of places to look
23/08/07 16:28:26 INFO PlatformInfo: Unable to read clusterId from /var/lib/instance-controller/extraInstanceData.json, trying EMR job-flow data file: /var/lib/info/job-flow.json
23/08/07 16:28:26 INFO PlatformInfo: Unable to read clusterId from http://localhost:8321/configuration, trying extra instance data file: /var/lib/instance-controller/extraInstanceData.json
```